# Hyperlink button adds unwanted / unneeded backslashes to escape brackets

Tags: bug, markdown, hyperlinks, editor

I have the following code snippet: `List<T[]>`, which is an ordinary Java type using array syntax.

Now, I want to put a link on that snippet, so I'm using the hyperlink button ([image: Hyperlink button]), or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> from the buttons above the edit area on the code snippet selection.

This is the result with unwanted backslashes: [`List<T\[\]>`](http://www.example.com)

Workaround: Manually removing the backslashes again: [`List<T[]>`](http://www.example.com)